# Division operator considered a regexp delimiter

Tags: ruby

Ruby (ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14) [x64-mingw32]) is parsing a sequence "ident-space-slash-number" as something starting a regular epxression:

```
irb(main):030:0> x = 10
=> 10
irb(main):031:0> x /2
irb(main):032:0/ /
SyntaxError: (irb):32: unterminated regexp meets end of file
```

(Line #32 is just there to make irb finish the parsing. At the end of line #31, the first `/` is already treated as a regexp delimiter.)

With different spacing or different operators it works as expected:

```
irb(main):033:0> x / 2
=> 5
irb(main):034:0> x/ 2
=> 5
irb(main):035:0> x/2
=> 5
irb(main):036:0> x *2
=> 20
```

Is this a bug? Based on what assumption would the parser see a reqular expression in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, run `irb` with warnings enabled to have a better understanding of what is going on (unrelevant warnings are omitted):

```
$ irb -w
irb:001> x = 0
=> 0
irb:002> x /2
irb:003/ /
(irb):2: warning: `/' after local variable or literal is interpreted as binary operator
(irb):2: warning: even though it seems like regexp literal
SyntaxError: (irb):3: unterminated regexp meets end of file
```

On line 2 the [Ruby lexer](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L6937) detects that `x` is a local variable so it assumes that the following `/` is a binary operator not the beginning of a regexp. On line 3 raises an error because a `/` by itself is an incomplete regexp.

This happens because IRB uses a [lexer](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb) to know if the expression you entered is complete, and therefore can be sent to Ruby for execution, or if you need to provide more input to complete the expression. The IRB's lexer can't detect what `x` is, so it assumes that it is a method and tries to interpret the rest of the line (`/2`) as the argument to `x`, since it is an unterminated regexp IRB ask you to complete it on line 3, thus the code sent by IRB to the Ruby parser is invalid as explained above.

For comparison consider what happens when `x` is actually a method:

```
$ irb -w
irb:001> def x; end
=> :x
irb:002> x /2
irb:003/ /
(irb):2: warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
        from (irb):1:in `x'
        from (irb):2
```

In this case both Ruby and IRB agree on the way the expression have to be parsed and you got an error because you are trying to pass an argument (namely `/2\n/`) to the `x` method which expects none.

To the point: it is a bug or not? Maybe it is a bug or maybe it is just a compromise to keep the IRB's lexer simple, I can't really tell.

Comment: Can you try `x /2` instead of `y = x /2` ?

Comment: @undur_gongor I've edited the answer, I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @toro2k: It totally does. So they key is there are two different lexers involved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As you defined `x = 10`. It is sure to Ruby parser that, `x` is a local variable. But now when you write `x /2`, Ruby hopes, there is a method called `x` also and `x /2` treated as `x(/2)`. But it is `/2` syntactically incorrect, so Ruby seems you are going to give the method `x` a regexp object. But in the last line when you wrote `/`, Still the same confusion Ruby parser is having. Thus it complains, your regexp literals is unterminated.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't get it. If the space alone makes the `x` a method name, why doesn't `x *2` get parsed as `x(*2)`?

Comment: It *is* parsed as `x.*(2)`

Comment: @Agis: Yes, and that's something entirely different than `x(*2)`.

Comment: @undur_gongor What is `x(*2)` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

*This is partly to compliment Arup's answer*

Take a look at the [Regexp class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) documentation. The opening paragraph says:

> ... Regexps are created using the /.../ and %r{...} literals, and by the Regexp::new constructor...

So as Arup said, the ruby parser interprets the `/2` portion of the line as the beginning of the creation of a Regexp literal, very much in the same way as `"2` would be interpreted as the beginning of the creation of a String literal.

Comment: Yes, that's obviously true. The question is more why that decision is different in the other three cases.

Comment: Because it *is* different.

Comment: @Agis: `x / 2` -- Here the slash is not treated as regexp delimiter although it could very well be one, e.g. `str.scan / 2 /`. What is the decision criterion?

Comment: @undur_gongor Agis is basically right that "that's just how it works", but that's a fair question, if you want more in-depth details. I can add something more fleshed out shortly (unless someone else does it before me).

Comment: @undur_gongor Actually `str.scan / 2 /` raises `syntax error, unexpected $end`. It seems you have discovered the most ambiguos corner of the Ruby syntax! :-)

Comment: @PaulRichter: That would be appreciated very much.